# How to implement a Checkstyle Regexp rule in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, checkstyle

In my team, we have switched from using Checkstyle and FindBugs to SonarQube, for many reasons, and particularly because of the dashboards, as they make it easier to have a global view of where we stand.

However, in the process, we have lost a few useful checks that I am trying to convert / reimplement with SonarQube. In particular, our Java code (legacy and newer) is plagued by a use of several logging platforms/libraries: slf4j+logback, Commons Logging, Java Util Logging, etc.

My use case for the Regexp in Checkstyle is to define a rule so that the only imports allowed for logging are based on slf4j.

SonarQube maintains a page that gives the implementation status of Checkstyle rules and I see Regexp in [the list of rejected rules](https://dist.sonarsource.com/reports/coverage/checkstyle.html#standard_rejected).

Is there a means to implement the Regexp rule or is it just a use case that will not be? I haven't been able to find an explanation of the rejection of each of the rejected rules, to see if there were recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your usecase I think you can make use of Disallowed class rule template : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/RSPEC-3688 to track where the improper loggers are used.