# How to restore custom rules after a SonarQube migration

Tags: sonarqube

I have defined a few days ago, after receiving an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50949936/2749913), two rules for forbidding the use of specific classes in our Java code. The starting point for defining them was the Squid:S3688 rule template ("Track uses of disallowed classes").

However, I have yesterday migrated the SonarQube 6.7.2 instance installed on my Windows 10 laptop to the most recent LTS (v6.7.4). As prescribed, I installed the newer version in a different folder while reusing the existing database. Upon inspection, everything looked fine.

My problem is that the web UI of SonarQube no longer shows the two custom rules. I thought the migration had somehow removed them. But when I tried to redefine the first one, I got this message:

> A rule with the key 'NO_APACHE_COMMONS_LOGGING' already exists.

I agree that the rule already exists: I created it like a week ago. But I do not see it in the UI, no matter how I search for it:

- the page of the rule template does not list any custom rules that implement the rule template,
- I do not see the custom rule when viewing the profile used by my team
- Search results are empty.

I went to the PostgreSQL database to see whether the rule was in the **rules** table and it is indeed there, just like the other rule "NO_LOG4J_LOGGING" that I've created. All values in the columns of the record are consistent with what I defined.

I have set the log levels to TRACE, hoping to see the generated SQL, but I didn't learn much from the logs.

My question: is there anything to do to restore/retrieve custom rules after a migration? I mean, apart from tampering with the database.